# Published website, but it now displays an error page instead of homepage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web, runtime-error

The error states:

> An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Here's the address where you can see the error:
http://connellchamberofcommerce.com/

I have a feeling there's something in the web.config I'm supposed to change now that the website is online instead of my local machine, but this is my first ASP.Net website and I don't know what it is.

Is there something simple I'm missing that you're supposed to do when publishing an ASP.Net website?

Comment: That's .NET's default error page. Did you try setting <customErrors mode="Off" /> in the web.config? That should display a more helpful error message. Do you have access to the error logs? If the actual error is getting logged somewhere you may be able to address it that way.

Answer (score 0):

In order to diagnose errors for your initial deployment, you can make the following change to your `web.config`.

```
<configuration>
...
    <system.web>
...
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
...
    </system.web>
...
</configuration>
```

You should change this back to `RemoteOnly` when you have resolved all your deployment exceptions to prevent unsavory folks from learning too much about your architecture.